# Indexing Wikipedia's Links to Make a Graph

Tags: python, xml, algorithm, memory, graph

I downloaded the Wikipedia dumps(the first torrent on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download)) and tried to index all the links by storing them in a python dictionary. I stored the links as a list of destinations in a dictionary with a key of the current page. However as I processed the dump I ended up with a MemoryError, so I decided to assign each page an integer ID. This got me farther but I still ended up with a MemoryError. What can I do to process this without that? I would prefer to store it all in memory. As my code is reasonably long I posted it [here](http://pastebin.com/Y6XfeYK5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start to looking at databases so as to index your id and the related links.

For a start you could have a try at [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/).

And here a starting point [at python database handling.](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseInterfaces)

I'm personnaly fond of [Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/) used in conjunction with python module psycopg2